# Google Maps API drawing line between two inputs

Tags: geolocation

So I have my suspicions that the reason this isn't working is because of my "var points.." line of code. I tried to store the results of the searches into something so I could use it later in the drawing function, but haven't cracked it yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<header> 
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { width: 1000px; height: 100% }

    </style>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var geoResults = {};
      var geocoder;
      var map;
      function initialize() {
          geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
          var myOptions = {
              zoom: 8,
              center: latlng,
          }
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
      }

      function codeAddress(id) {
          var address = document.getElementById(id).value;
          geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map,
                      position: results[0].geometry.location
                  });

                  searchResults[id] = results[0].geometry.location;


              } else {
                  alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }
          });

          function drawLine() {
              var points = [searchResults.address1, searchResults.address2];
              var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                  path: points,
                  strokeColor: '#ff0000',
                  strokeWeight: 5,
                  strokeOpacity: 0.7,
                  map: map
              });

          }
      }
      function clearDiv1() {
          document.getElementById("address1").value = "";
      }

      function clearDiv2() {
          document.getElementById("address2").value = "";
      }

  </script> 
</header> 

<body onload="initialize()"> 

  <div> 
    <input id="address1" type="text"> 
    <button type="button" onclick="codeAddress('address1')">Search Start Address</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="clearDiv1()">Clear</button>
  </div> 
  <div> 
   <input id="address2" type="text""> 
   <button type="button" value="Search End Address" onclick="codeAddress('address2')">Submit End Address</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="clearDiv2()">Clear</button>
  </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="drawLine()">DRAW</button>
    </div>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you had a few syntax errors

Here is the working jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wXV7t/1/

and the updated code

```
        <!DOCTYPE html> 

<header> 
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { width: 1000px; height: 100% }

    </style>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var geoResults = {};
      var geocoder;
      var map;
      var searchResults = [];
      function initialize() {
          geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
          var myOptions = {
              zoom: 8,
              center: latlng,
          }
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
      }

      function codeAddress(id) {
          var address = document.getElementById(id).value;
          geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map,
                      position: results[0].geometry.location
                  });

                  searchResults[id] = results[0].geometry.location;

              } else {
                  alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }
          });


      }

       function drawLine() {
              var points = [searchResults.address1, searchResults.address2];
              var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                  path: points,
                  strokeColor: '#ff0000',
                  strokeWeight: 5,
                  strokeOpacity: 0.7,
                  map: map
              });

          }

      function clearDiv1() {
          document.getElementById("address1").value = "";
      }

      function clearDiv2() {
          document.getElementById("address2").value = "";
      }

  </script> 
</header> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 
  <div> 
    <input id="address1" type="text"> 
    <button type="button" onclick="codeAddress('address1')">Search Start Address</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="clearDiv1()">Clear</button>
  </div> 
  <div> 
   <input id="address2" type="text""> 
   <button type="button" value="Search End Address" onclick="codeAddress('address2')">Submit End Address</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="clearDiv2()">Clear</button>
  </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="drawLine()">DRAW</button>
    </div>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div> 
</body>
```